# duplicates sorted to CSV listing all duplicate references pandas

Tags: pandas, duplicates

Given this sample data frame with duplicates, I am trying to organize these duplicates in to separate csv output files so that every law firm that has a duplicate gets a list of those duplicates AND the name of the other firm associated with that duplicate.

```
Client       SSN     Law Firm
Jones        1111     A
Jones        1111     B
Smith        2222     A
Smith        2222     C
Williams     3333     B
Jones        3333     C
```

Expected CSV output:

'Law Firm A.csv'

```
Client       SSN      Law Firm

Jones        1111     Law Firm A
Jones        1111     Law Firm B
Smith        2222     Law Firm A
Smith        2222     Law Firm C
```

'Law Firm B.csv'

```
Client          SSN      Law Firm

Jones           1111     Law Firm A
Jones           1111     Law Firm B
Williams        3333     Law Firm B
Williams        3333     Law Firm C
```

I tried sorting the overall workbook by by firm, but saving only those rows associated with a particular firm does not allow for saving also, any of that firm's clients also associated with any other firm.  Hence my question.  Even getting my overall data to this format resulted from transforms, a pivot table and reindexing, phew, just a lot of pottery with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter by `Law Firm` and use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) on resulting `SSN`:

```
df[df["SSN"].isin(df[df['Law Firm']=="A"]["SSN"])]
```

Comment: Fantastic.  I was viewing this from the wrong perspective and it always helps to reach out.  Thanks for this solution.  Worked perfectly and solved a huge problem for me.